# How to stop redundancy in sql query?

Tags: mysql, distinct

i have a problem in searching query. My result set columns are repeating columns. My query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, b.first_name,c.category_name 
FROM 
  songs_upload a 
  inner join Artist b 
    on a.title like '%ab%' 
       and b.first_name like '%chandan%' 
  inner join Categories c
    on c.category_name like '%POP%'
```

Comment: Can you give an example of data, results, and expected results?

Comment: What do you mean by repeating column in result set? What are you table declaration?

Comment: yes dear my result set repeating results like this...
616  chandan  POP_music
616  chandan  POP
626  chandan  POP_music
626  chandan  POP

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are doing `select a.* ...` and surely other tables (`b` and `c`) have   columns with the same name. Specify explicitly the columns that you want to select from each table and avoid using `select *` as this is terrible practice, anyway.

Why is this bad practice? Imagine some time in the future table `a` is added a BLOB column in the future that stores big amounts of data. Your query will end up bringing back that column even though you don't need it, and your query performance will be decreased substantially.

Your query should be something like:

```
select a.colum_I_want, 
       a.other_column_I_want, 
       b.first_name,
       c.category_name 
FROM 
  songs_upload a 
  inner join Artist b 
    on a.title like '%ab%' 
       and b.first_name like '%chandan%' 
  inner join Categories c
    on c.category_name like '%POP%'
```

Comment: But dear this way we cant stop redundancy. Many columns are still repeating